# Procedure sp_cdc_enable_db_internal, Line 49 The database 'DBname' cannot be enabled for Change Data Capture

Tags: sql-server, database, cdc

Hi I had ssms 2012 developer and enable cdc role but not worked ...
then I reinstall windows , and install ssms 2014 enterprice then restore my database . 
But now when I want to Enable CDC for my database with this query :

```
exec sys.sp_cdc_enable_db
```

I get this Error :

> Msg 22906, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_cdc_enable_db_internal,
>   Line 49 The database 'DBname' cannot be enabled for Change Data
>   Capture because a database user named 'cdc' or a schema named 'cdc'
>   already exists in the current database. These objects are required
>   exclusively by Change Data Capture. Drop or rename the user or schema
>   and retry the operation.

also when i select name , is_cdc_enabled from sys.databases  cdc value is 0

when I try to drop cdc Schemas get this Error :

> Cannot drop schema 'cdc' because it is being referenced by object
>   'fn_cdc_get_all_changes_ ... '. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3729)

How I can remove cdc and all cdc object and reEnable it ? or How i can solve exec sys.sp_cdc_enable_db ! in the last ssms ( version 2012 developer ) when I checked is_cdc_enabled the value was 1 .

Comment: That seems like an odd state for the database to be in. Have you tried running `sp_cdc_disable_db` for this database? If that doesn't work, you may need examine the code for *that* procedure and do what it does by hand.

Comment: yes i test it and not work ! finally I generate script from my tables , sp and .. then delete and agane create my DB ...